# ArgumentParser -h not printing options after parse_known_args

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have script with a long list of optional arguments where I recently added the option to pass the arguments through a file. The code for this is below: I first add the `from_file` args and then `parse_known_args`. Everything works except for the `-h` flag. The output when calling this flag only refers to the arguments added before the `parse_known_args` call.

**Question:** how can I get the help option to recognize all arguments after the `parse_known_args` call?

```
# grab values from file_parser or default
def getInitVar(variable, parser, default, varList=False):
    if parser:
        if varList:
            return [o.strip() for o in parser.get('constants',variable).split(",")] if parser.has_option('constants',variable) else default
        else:
            return parser.get('constants',variable) if parser.has_option('constants',variable) else default
    else:
        return default

# first parser for to/from file parameters
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='', prefix_chars='-+', formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

# Meta variables
group = parser.add_argument_group('Meta Variables', '')
group.add_argument('--to_file', dest='toinitfile', nargs='?', const=DEF_INIT_FILE, default=None,
                  help='write flag values to text file')
group.add_argument('--from_file', type=str, dest='frominitfile', default='',
                   help='reads flag values from file')

args, remaining_argv = parser.parse_known_args()

# create second parser for reading from files
if args.frominitfile:
    conf_parser = SafeConfigParser()
    conf_parser.read(args.frominitfile)
else:
    conf_parser = None

group = parser.add_argument_group('Some Group', 'blah blah')

group.add_argument('-someFlag', dest='somevar', default=getInitVar('corpdb', conf_parser, DEF_VAR),
                    help='Some help.')
....
```

Output when using the `-h` flag:

```
optional arguments:
-h, --help            show this help message and exit

Meta Variables:
--to_file [TOINITFILE]
                    write flag values to text file (default: None)
--from_file FROMINITFILE
                    reads flag values from file (default: )
```

**EDIT:** Added some details (as suggested in the comments) to my code as to why I am calling `parse_known_args`:

1. I create the parsers and add two arguments: `from_file` and `to_file`
2. Parse the arguments. If `from_file` is present I create a second parser and read the input variable.
3. Continue adding arguments to the parser. Default value is a function to which I pass the second parser and default value.

**EDIT:** Finally figured out how to do this, posted the answer below.

Comment: Options are only processed when you call `parse_args` or `parse_known_args`.  Of course you won't see any arguments added after that...they don't exist at the time you parsed the command line!

Comment: @larsks Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Don't call any of the `parse` functions until you have fully configured your ArgumentParser.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that's helpful. If you look at my post you can see that I am calling the `parse` function for a reason. :)

Comment: It's actually not clear from your code what you're doing with the parser object afterwards.  You are not calling one of the `.parse` arguments on it in your example other than the first time, nor are the new arguments you are adding conditional on the config file you read in.  Perhaps one of the answers here will help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made the following changes:

1. Created an `init_parser` with parameter `add_help=False`
2. Passed `init_parser` to `parser` as a parent: `parents=[init_parser]`
3. Move the description parameter from `init_parser` to `parser`

Here is the final code:

```
init_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prefix_chars='-+', formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter, add_help=False)

# Meta variables
group = init_parser.add_argument_group('Meta Variables', '')
group.add_argument('--to_file', dest='toinitfile', nargs='?', const=DEF_INIT_FILE, default=None, help='write flag values to text file')
group.add_argument('--from_file', type=str, dest='frominitfile', default='', help='reads flag values from file')

args, remaining_argv = init_parser.parse_known_args()

if args.frominitfile:
    conf_parser = SafeConfigParser()
    conf_parser.read(args.frominitfile)
else:
    conf_parser = None

# Inherit options from init_parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Extract and Manage Language Feature Data.', 
    parents=[init_parser])

group = parser.add_argument_group('Some Group', 'blah blah')

group.add_argument('-someFlag', dest='somevar', default=getInitVar('corpdb', conf_parser, DEF_VAR),
                    help='Some help.')
....
```

Output:

```
optional arguments:
    -h, --help            show this help message and exit

Meta Variables:
--to_file [TOINITFILE]
                write flag values to text file (default: None)
--from_file FROMINITFILE
                reads flag values from file (default: )
Some group:
    blah blah blah
--someFlag
...
```

Comment: This is one of the better uses of `parents` that I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are parsing the inputs, and based on certain values, adding further arguments, which you will again parse.  Right?

The `-h` is being handled by the first parsing.  Remember it exits after printing its arguments.  So it doesn't get to the `some group` addition, much less display the later help.

One way around this is to define the first parser with `add_help=False`, so the first `parse_know_args` does not handle the `-h`.

Now add your own `-h` argument to the parser (try `action='help'`); or recreate the parser.  Either way the second parsing step will act on the `-h`.